# MySQL query not working when a variable is used Inside the query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've encountered a strange issue where my MySQL query works for all cases except for one particular data entry.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_songs WHERE album_name = '{$current_album}'
```

This query is fed into the Wordpress $wpdb->get_results() function. For some reason it can never find this particular data entry: "Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape"

However, if the query is instead changed to:

```
 SELECT * FROM wp_songs WHERE album_name = 'Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape'
```

The data is found without a problem.

Running the $wpdb->last_query function returns the exact same line in both cases.

The issue is only for one data entry. I have not been able to replicate the problem with other data entries. All other entries work with my original query.

More code:

This does not work:

```
 $current_album = "Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape";
 $songs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_songs WHERE album_name = '{$current_album}'")
if ( $songs ) { echo "Works"; }
```

This works:

```
  $songs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_songs WHERE album_name = 'Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape'");
  if ( $songs ) { echo "Works"; }
```

Again, it's only for that specific data entry. Every other entry works with both queries.

Running var_dump($current_album) returns:

```
string(28) "Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape"
```

Comment: please show all the relevant code

Comment: try this construct with a string that does not contain special characters. I think th "&" and the ":" made the problems.

Comment: It works with a string that does not contain special characters, but it also works when I don't use a variable.

Comment: I think that's what Panique thought would happen.  This would show that the there's a bug in the wordpress expansion routine.

Comment: try using like? `SELECT * FROM wp_songs WHERE album_name LIKE '".$search."%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You posted the results of var_dumping $current album:

> string(28) "Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape"

"Raw & Uncut: The Mixtape" is only 24 characters - what that tells me is that your variable actually contains this:

`Raw &amp; Uncut: The Mixtape`

Which doesn't match what you have in the database.  You can correct it by running html_entity_decode() on your album variable.